# Powershell get interface from specific wlan

Tags: powershell

I wanna create a script in powershell, which gives me the interface of a WLAN.

An example:
I'm connected with WLAN A, but I want the interface from WLAN B. How can I get that?

Currently I'm using `netsh wlan show interface`. But with that I just get the interface from the currently connected WLAN.

Is it also possible, that I can do that, when I'm connected with a LAN-cable and wanna get the interface of a WLAN?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the interface of a WLAN"?

Comment: Something like that:
Name                   : WLAN
    Beschreibung           : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz
    GUID                   : 39efcc46-3726-43e4-9291-713903bef31a
    Physische Adresse      : 5c:80:b6:88:4a:fa
    Status                 : Verbunden
    SSID                   : VIN
    BSSID                  : b0:e1:7e:e4:ea:21
    Netzwerktyp            : Infrastruktur
    Funktyp                   : 802.11n
    Authentifizierung   : WPA2-Personal
    Verschlüsselung        : CCMP
    Verbindungsmodus          : Automat. Verbindung
    Kanal               : 1

Comment: But that's not going to change just because you connect to a different SSID - the underlying NIC is still the same, just connected to a different network?

Comment: I know it would be possible connecting directly to the WLAN, but I would like to select the WLAN in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# List all Network Adapters
Get-NetAdapter

# Get info on just Wireless Network
Get-NetAdapter -Name wi-fi | FL *

# Get more info on how to use Get-NetAdapter:
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=windowsserver2019-ps